# Twig generates too long URL resulting in a browser crash

Tags: apache, twig, vhosts, silex

I've got a really weird issue.

I'm developping localy a portfolio based on Silex and Twig through a VM. At first I was accessing it like this: 192.168.56.2/pfsilex and everything was working fine.

I've created a vhost and the corresponding entry in my host file, and I still can access my website and navigate between pages, but after a few seconds on the page the browser just crash (tried with Chrome, FF and IE).

At first I thought it was some kind of script, so I disabled JavaScript. Nothing changed. After checking the error.log from Apache I had weird entries : "Request URI too long". Very weird indeed considering my URIs are really short.
The next thing to do has been to check the access.log, and yes, URIs are way too long:

```
192.168.56.1 - - [28/Jan/2013:22:37:40 +0100] "GET /[type:protected]%20=%3E%200%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20[lineno:protected]%20=%3E%201%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20[1]%20=%3E%20Twig_Token%20Object%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20[value:protected]%20=%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20[type:protected]%20=%3E%202%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20[lineno:protected]%20=%3E%207%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20[2]%20=%3E%20Twig_Token%20Object%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%" 414 540 "-" "-"
```

In this URI we can notice twice the parameter named "Twig_Token" which let me thing that's a Twig issue, but since it's totaly working without the virtual host I'm kinda lost.
I don't pass any get parameters to my views (at least it seems so but I'm new to Silex), only arguments when returning the template.

I don't think it comes directly from twig.

Here is my vhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName portfolio.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/pfsilex/
        <Directory /var/www/pfsilex/>
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride All
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess :

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And my host :

```
192.168.56.2    portfolio.dev
```

Comment: What's the code that generates the above url?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just requesting "/" and I have my "/" method doing an SQL query then passing the result to the view, that's all.

Comment: Your question does not have enough information to help. For starters you should find the code I asked about. You should be able to find it easily by comparing your twig files and the html output of your index page.

Comment: I know what code returns the corresponding views. I haven't write anything that generates that kind of URL.

Comment: Still, there's somehow a reference to it. Did you check your html output as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, and I can't find any reference :/

Comment: I've added my vhost, .htaccess and host for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had nothing to do with Twig.

In fact I had a general route intercepting everything served on "/" in order to load pages from the DB.

But it means it was also intercepting every static file, and when this file was not present the method would throw a big stacktrace.

What was happening is that I hadn't any favicon.ico but every browser tries anyway to load it.
The Chrome network console doesn't show this resource loading, I was able to debug it using Firefox which show it.